# Difference In List - Python - Syntax Explanation

Tags: python, list

Can someone please explain the meaning the syntax behind the following line of code:

```
temp3 = [x for x in temp1 if x not in s]
```

I understand it's for finding the differences between 2 lists, but what does the 'x' represent here? Each individual element in the list that is being compared? I understand that `temp1` and `s` are lists. Also, does `x for x` have to have the same variable or could it be `x for y`?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It iterates through each element in `temp1` and checks to see if it is *not* in `s` before including it in `temp3`.

It is a shorter and more pythonic way of writing

```
temp3 = []
for item in temp1:
    if item not in s:
        temp3.append(item)
```

Where `temp1` and `s` are the two lists you are comparing.

As for your second question, `x for y` will work, but probably not in the way you intend to, and certainly not in a very useful way. It will assign each item in `temp1` to the variable name `y`, and then search for `x` in the scope outside of the list comprehension. Assuming `x` is defined previously (otherwise you will get `NameError` or something similar), the condition `if x not in s` will evaluate to the same thing for every item in `temp1`, which is why it’s not terribly useful. And if that condition is true, your resulting `temp3` will be populated with `x`s; the `y` values are unused.

Do not take this as saying that using different variables in a list comprehension is never useful. In fact list comprehensions like `[a if condition(x) else b for x in original_sequence]` are often *very* useful. A list comprehension like `[a for x in original_sequence if condition(x)]` can also be useful for constructing a list containing exactly as many instances of `a` as the number of items in `original_sequence` that satisfy `condition()`.

Answer (score 4):

```
[x for x in temp1 if x not in s]
```

It may help to re-order it slightly, so you can read the whole thing left to right. Let's move the first `x` to the end.

```
[for x in temp1 if x not in s yield x]
```

I've added a fake `yield` keyword so it reads naturally as English. If we then add some colons it becomes even clearer.

```
[for x in temp1: if x not in s: yield x]
```

Really, this is the order that things get evaluated in. The `x` variable comes from the `for` loop, that's why you can refer to it in the `if` and `yield` clauses. But the way list comprehensions are written is to put the value being yielding at the front. So you end up using a variable name that's not yet defined.

In fact, this final rewrite is exactly how you'd write an explicit generator function.

```
def func(temp1, s):
    for x in temp1:
        if x not in s:
            yield x
```

If you call `func(temp1, s)` you get a generator equivalent to the list. You could turn it into that list with `list(func(temp1, s))`.

Answer (score 0):

Try yourself:

```
arr = [1,2,3]
[x+5 for x in arr]
```

This should give you [6, 7, 8] that are the values on the [1,2,3] list plus 5. This syntax is know as list comprehension (or mapping). It applies the same instructions to all elements on a list. Would be the same as doing this:

```
for x in arr:
    arr += 5
```

Answer (score -2):

X is same variable and it is not y. It works same as below code

```
newList = []
for x in temp1:
   if x not in s:
   newList.append(x)
```

So `x for x`, here first is x which is inside append in code and x after for is same as for x in temp1.